# Which is the table that stores the data model name of a BI report in Oracle Fusion?

Tags: oracle, datamodel, fusion

I want to fetch the data model name of a given report using a query in BI in Oracle fusion.
Which table stores the data model name of a repor.

gl_frc_reports_b table stores the report name and path of all BI and OTBI reports, likewise there must be a table that will hold the data model details of a report

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this? I have noticed that the table GL_FRC_REPORTS_B does not always match the current report structure we have defined in our Catalog. It seems like this table is not refreshed. Do you know if there is some process to refresh it?